# Trouble vectorizing code

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I'm having a hard time on doing this. I have two m x n matrices (A and B) and I need to multiply every column of A by the rows in B, to generate a m x (n*n) matrix. I guess I wasn't very clear in the explanation so I'll post an example:

```
A = 
[1 2 
 3 4]
B = 
[5 6
 7 8]
```

I wish to have:

```
 [[5 6] [10 12]
  [21 24] [28 32]]
```

I was able to do it using `for` loops but I want to avoid `for` as much as possible. Also using numpy to all this and all data is stored as `np.array`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe:

```
>>> A = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
>>> B = np.array([[5,6],[7,8]])
>>> (A * B[None, :].T).T
array([[[ 5,  6],
        [21, 24]],

       [[10, 12],
        [28, 32]]])
```

where we use `None` to add an extra dimension to `B`, and a few transpositions to get the alignment right.

Comment: @DSM, nice work. Is it convention to use `None` to increase the rank of the array?

Comment: @agconti: well, I think it's Officially Recommended(tm) to use `np.newaxis` as the name, but `np.newaxis` is simply another name for `None`.  In principle though they could change it to another sentinel.

Comment: @DSM thanks! I've run into `newaxis` in the docs, but I never knew it was the same as `None`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, you want basic ( m * n ) multiplication right? Use [numpy.dot()](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html):

```
>>> a = [[1, 0], [0, 1]]
>>> b = [[4, 1], [2, 2]]
>>> np.dot(a, b)
array([[4, 1],
       [2, 2]])
```

Comment: The expected output provided by the OP clearly suggests that basic multiplication is not what they need.

Comment: Actually no, and I don't know how to explain it clearly, so I believe the best thing to understand what I want is to look at the example